# How to disable --keyboard-offset in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I'm playing around with Ionic and I'm wondering is there's a way to disable the offset Ionic adds to the page when typing on mobile with `--keyboard-offset`.

Right now the offset messes up my UI, I would like to disable it completely if possible.

Answer (score 7):

I was in the same problems, a simple fixe I come up with is to put this to override `--keyboard-offset` properties on each pages:

```css
ion-content{
   --keyboard-offset: 0 !important;
}
```